# Why my query didn't give the right Count and Max?

Tags: sql, date, count, max

Send Date, Total opens, Last Open date (if there is any open), Total clicks, Last Click date (if there is any open)

```
create table TBLA(Email text, SendID text, SendDate date, OpenDate date, ClickDate date);

insert into TBLA values("aaa@gmail.com", "ABCD1234", "8/1/2019",'1/8/2019',"8/1/2019");
insert into TBLA values("aaa@gmail.com", "ABCD1234", "8/1/2019",'2/8/2019',"");
insert into TBLA values("aaa@gmail.com", "ABCD1234", "8/1/2019",'3/8/2019',"8/3/2019");
insert into TBLA values("bbb@gmail.com", "ABCD1234", "8/1/2019",'1/8/2019',"");
insert into TBLA values("bbb@gmail.com", "ABCD1234", "8/1/2019",'2019/8/15',"8/15/2019");
insert into TBLA values("ccc@gmail.com", "ABCD1234", "8/1/2019","","");
insert into TBLA values("ddd@gmail.com", "ABCD1234", "8/1/2019","","");
insert into TBLA values("aaa@gmail.com", "xyz123", "8/2/2019","8/2/2019","8/2/2019");
insert into TBLA values("aaa@gmail.com", "xyz123", "8/2/2019","8/15/2019","");
insert into TBLA values("bbb@gmail.com", "xyz123", "8/2/2019","","");
insert into TBLA values("ccc@gmail.com", "xyz123", "8/2/2019","8/5/2019","8/5/2019");


select SendID," ", SendDate," ",count(OpenDate), " ", max(OpenDate), " ", count(ClickDate), " ", max(ClickDate)
from TBLA 
where SendID = "ABCD1234" AND (OpenDate<>"" AND ClickDate<>"");
```

The count(OpenDate) must be 5 and max(OpenDate) must be 8/15/2019. Count(ClickDate) must be 3.

Comment: You have an aggregation query with unaggregated columns in the `SELECT`.  There is no `GROUP BY`.  The query looks syntactically invalid.

Comment: I add GROUP BY and there is no change.  I reduce my query : Select count(OpenDate), max(OpenDate) from TBLA where SendID="ABCD1234" AND OpenDate <>"" group by SendID;  

The result is good for the Count but the max date is " 8/3/2019".   Why is not "8/15/2019" ?

Comment: @JulieLevesque Your date is in string format that is why "8/3/2019" is greater than "8/15/2019". You need to convert the date in string format to date in datetime format using convert function.

Comment: I'm surprised your code even run.  There're so many things wrong with the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @nagarwal pointed out there is a data type problem. The date fields are declared as dates but receive strings as input.
Since you are inputting the data manually, I think simply using this 'YYYY-MM-DD' syntax for the date will do the trick.

Comment: I change the date fields in Text. I change the format in the Insert for 'YYYY-MM-DD'. But in Select Max(Date(OpenDate)) from TBLA, doesn't work.  I am in SqlLite, To_date doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

you can use to_date function to insert the dates column to your table and this will solve the issue

Comment: I found : Select Max(strftime('%m/%d/%Y',OpenDate)) from TBLA;    The answer is '08/15/2019'.  Thanks a lot at all